# Gridview is not updating after databind is called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 gridviews in 3 different updatepanels, which i update them after `RowCommand`.

```
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView2.DataBind();
GridView3.DataBind();
```

The weird thing is only `GridView1_RowCommand` can update all three gridview. `GridView2_RowCommand` using the same method but i cannot update the gridview. 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for Rowcommand:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //check the commandName
    if (e.CommandName != "SaveStartTime")
        return;

    int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string id = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text;

    Label time = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("ActualTimeStart") as Label;
    time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

    var Cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SqlExpress;Database=CMOS;Trusted_Connection=True";

    Cn.Open();

    var Cm = Cn.CreateCommand();

    string store = string.Format(@"UPDATE [ApprovedExitPass] SET ActualTimeStart = '{0}' WHERE Id='{1}'", time.Text, id);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(store, Cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualTimeStart", time.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Cn.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //check the commandName
    if (e.CommandName != "SaveReturnTime")
        return;

    int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string id = GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].Text;
    Response.Write(id);
    Label time = GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("ActualTimeArrive") as Label;
    time.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    var Cn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
    Cn.ConnectionString = "Server=.\\SqlExpress;Database=CMOS;Trusted_Connection=True";

    Cn.Open();

    var Cm = Cn.CreateCommand();

    string store = string.Format(@"UPDATE [ApprovedExitPass] SET ActualTimeArrive = '{0}' WHERE Id='{1}'", time.Text, id);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(store, Cn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActualTimeArrive", time.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Cn.Close();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    GridView2.DataBind();
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please add more code, including `GridView1_RowCommand`.

Comment: very difficult to determine what you are seeing or not seeing based on what you have posted.. please edit this question and post all relevant code , methods and or events..

Comment: I updated the code. Both using the same update method but only `GridView1_RowCommand` can update all 3 gridview.

Comment: @Wen21 yes `gridview1_rowcommand` will update all three because if you see the  `gridview1_rowcommand`  in that method you are calling the databind of other two gridviews also . so now why this happening only while calling  `gridview1_rowcommand`  because you might be probably calling first grid row command.

Comment: @webruster, thanks you for ur comment. After see ur comment, i check back my code and i find out the `Response.Write` is causing the gridview databind not working. Thx...

Answer (score 0):

**YES**,`gridview1_rowcommand` will update all three because if you see the `gridview1_rowcommand`.in that method you are calling the databind of other two gridviews also . so now why this happening only while calling `gridview1_rowcommand` because you might be probably calling first grid row command or some other Issue.

SO probably Verify whether you getting value in `Response.write(id)`